# How do I transfer books and news articles to my Kindle device from my computer?

Tags: kindle, calibre

I want to transfer books and news articles from my **computer** to my Kindle.

I did some research and found that I can use a program called Calibre.

However, I noticed that Calibre emails the content to my kindle email address. This can take a really long time.

My question is:

**Is it necessary to put my kindle email address in Calibre to transfer the content to my Kindle? Is the upload from my PC to my Kindle separate from the email process? Is the emailing process just a backup measure of some kind?** I don't understand what it is for.

Answer (score 1):

To load/update books, Kindle uses Amazons WhisperNet. You can send content to your Kindle email address to get it transfered to your device via Whispernet.

I'm not sure whether the Kindle can be accessed directly -- but you can [Download a User Guide](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_kindle_nav_ts_guide?ie=UTF8&nodeId=200317150) and check for yourself. Moreover, you could consult [Adding Books to the Kindle With Calibre](http://madravings.xtreemhost.com/CalibreInst.htm).

An easy way for you could be to use Calibres integrated web server, and access your library directly from your Kindle. This is described in the Calibre manual: [Can I access my calibre books using the web browser in my Kindle or other reading device?](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html#can-i-access-my-app-books-using-the-web-browser-in-my-kindle-or-other-reading-device).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the format of the content you want to include and your specific model of Kindle.  In general, you can transfer `.mobi` files directly to the Kindle using a USB cable.  Put them in the `Books` or `Documents` folders on the Kindle (differs by your specific model) and they should appear automatically when you disconnect from the computer.  [There are step-by-step instructions here](http://www.ehow.com/how_5943135_transfer-documents-kindle-computer.html), though keep in mind that you will want to put ebooks in the Books folder on a Kindle Fire (and possibly other, newer Kindles), or else they will show up in the wrong place on the device.

If you have files of a different format, such as `.PDF` or `.epub` then you probably need to convert them.  (PDF can be viewed directly on some Kindles, but it doesn't always display in a reading-friendly format, so conversion is advised.)  Calibre is one tool that you could use to convert them to `.mobi` or you can Google `"convert xyz into mobi"` (where xyz is the particular file type you have) and you should find several sites and programs that can do the conversion.

As for the email address, that is a "backup measure" in that it is the simplest way to do it for most users, and Amazon does not target their devices only to the technically minded, so most users can just email what they want to see on their Kindle and it will show up.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to be able to transfer books and really any file at all without any sort of cables or e-mail, then you can use this method:
http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Kindle_Touch_Hacking#Jailbreak

I haven't actually tried it myself (I don't have a kindle) but I used a similar method to establish ssh abilities to my iphone.